# How does loudness decrease with distance?

Tags: waves, acoustics, volume, distance

Let's say there's a speaker in a huge open space on the Earth's surface. The speaker blares a sine wave with frequency $f$ Hz and and volume $V_0$ decibels.

How does the volume (in decibels) decrease as a function of distance $r$ from the speaker? I'd also like to know how the loudness depends on the initial volume and frequency. A rough answer in terms of big-$\Theta$ notation would be great.

E.g. Acceleration due to gravity is in $\Theta\left(\frac{M}{r^2}\right)$

Feel free to make any simplifying assumptions you want (e.g. there's no wind).